# What's more efficient? Storing variable references vs not (Context in Android)

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization

Let's say we are in the middle of a method. And I have a choice between two styles of programming.

Option A: use `getContext().getResources()` every time I need to access resources

```
public void doSomeStuffA(){
  //...
  getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow);      //...
}
```

**Option B**: Store `getContext().getResources()` in a variable.

```
public void doSomeStuffB(){
  //...
  Resources r = getContext().getResources();
  r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
  //...
}
```

Which style is better?

Comment: If you are calling methods on resources so many times, its better to use option B. But sometimes if resources keep on changing and you have to call a method on the latest value of resource use option A

Comment: You mean vice versa?

Comment: I corrected it sorry  :P

Comment: @Vwin I shortened it from 4 to 2 times. Is it still better to use Option A?

Comment: I would still use the above mentioned rule and use option B if resources don't change. There might not be a major efficiency change but still its a good practice. whereas if you have a single tstament i would go with option A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so much in performance and tuning, the correct answer is "it depends".  99 percent of the time, the difference between an extra hashmap dereference versus a variable reference is not the biggest (or even noticable) performance issue.  The trick is to understand when it is likely to be an issue (frequent calls in tight loops for example).

Within a single method, I would tend to use option B primarily for readability.

Answer (score 1):

As a general practice (Not in particular this case)

Use Option A:

- Resources keep on changing and you want the most recent value of resource.
- If you are calling methods on resource just once.

Use Option B:

- Resources don't change then you can use a reference and use it wherever you want.

Comment: So, use option B any time you need to reference a variable more than once in the same scope? (assuming the resources do not change in between references)

Comment: Yes that is what I would do. and its definitely better than getting resources everytime

Comment: resources are immutable, how could they change?

Comment: I was talking in general sense. Instead of calling a method twice to get something, call once and use that reference

Answer (score 0):

Use Kotlin to make everything neat and clean )

```
fun someFun() {
    with(getContext()) {
        var d1 = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic1)
        val d2 = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic2)
        ...
    }
}
```